# Taking value of data jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drag-drop action in my code. Everytime when i drag and drop into <**ul id="sortable1"**> i get an <**li**> with <**data-score(1, 2 or 3)**> like:

If i drag 2 items in my ul i will have:

```
<ul id="sortable1">
   <li data-score="2"> A </li>
   <li data-score="1"> B </li>
</ul>
```

My question is: **How can i count that data-score into a input with total-data-score attribute?** 
<**input total-data-score="2+1 (from A+B data-score)"**>

I had tried a each function, but it doesn't help me...

```
var score = 0;
$("ul#sortable1 li").each(function(){
   score += $("ul#sortable1 li").data("score");
})
console.log(score);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use context `this` in each function:

```
var score = 0;
$("ul#sortable1 li").each(function(){
  score += $(this).data("score");
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/088cncmf/)**

Comment: @Tushar: not needed. data returns the value with its type. where as attr do not. see this http://jsfiddle.net/ef2mh56z/

Comment: @ColarPaul: glad it helps :)

Comment: More 1 little question. how can i put that data, into my input with id total-data-score?

$("#total-data-score").val(score);?

Comment: $("#questionH").attr(("total-score"), score); This worked. Thank you for answer. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var score = 0;
$("ul#sortable1 li").each(function(){
   score += $(this).data("score");
})
console.log(score);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8odovp6a/ - demo.